# Qt scrollbar synchronization

Tags: c++, qt

I want to synchronize the scrolling of the two widgets(textEdit1 and textEdit2).

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QScrollBar>

class MainWindow : public QDialog{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QDialog(parent)
    {
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout(this));
        QTabWidget *tabWidget = new QTabWidget();
        layout()->addWidget(tabWidget);

        QString text = "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n";

        QTextEdit *textEdit1 = new QTextEdit(tabWidget);
        textEdit1->setText(text);
        tabWidget->addTab(textEdit1, "1");

        QTextEdit *textEdit2 = new QTextEdit(tabWidget);
        textEdit2->setText(text);
        tabWidget->addTab(textEdit2, "2");


        //Scrollbar synchronization
        connect(textEdit1->verticalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                textEdit2->verticalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int)));
        connect(textEdit2->verticalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                textEdit1->verticalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int)));

        setMaximumHeight(100);
    }
};
```

But it only works when I open a tab with every widget.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you call `textEdit2->ensurePolished();` at the end of your constructor?

Comment: thuga, nothing. It works only if all the tabs opened at least once

Comment: I'm suspecting that the range isn't updated before the widget is shown.

Comment: vertical scrollbar needs height to calculate the handlle size. have you tried setting the height of the scrollbar 2 same as scrollbar 1?

Comment: ramtheconqueror, property "height" is readonly. Maybe you mean setRange or setMaximum?

PS:
textEdit2->verticalScrollBar()->setMaximum(textEdit1->verticalScrollBar()->maximum());
at the end of constructor does not work

Comment: or, you could use tab widget's `currentChanged` signal to update the scrollbar values? just a thought.